# What is define* in guile or scheme?

Tags: function, scheme, guile

I can't find it by searching, what is `define*` in guile? You can find it for instance in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24101699/387194

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will find it in the documentation here: Creating advanced argument handling procedures.

**6.10.4.1 lambda* and define*.**

> lambda* is like lambda, except with some extensions to allow optional
>   and keyword arguments.

```
library syntax: lambda* ([var…]
[#:optional vardef…]
[#:key vardef… [#:allow-other-keys]]
[#:rest var | . var])
body1 body2 …
```

> Optional and keyword arguments can also have default values to take
>   when not present in a call, by giving a two-element list of variable
>   name and expression. For example in

```
(define* (frob foo #:optional (bar 42) #:key (baz 73))
  (list foo bar baz))
```

> foo is a fixed argument, bar is an optional argument with default
>   value 42, and baz is a keyword argument with default value 73. Default
>   value expressions are not evaluated unless they are needed, and until
>   the procedure is called.
>
> Normally it’s an error if a call has keywords other than those
>   specified by #:key, but adding #:allow-other-keys to the definition
>   (after the keyword argument declarations) will ignore unknown
>   keywords.

From:

https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/docs/master/guile.html/lambda_002a-and-define_002a.html#lambda_002a-and-define_002a

Answer (score 3):

In the Scheme standard `define*` is not defined but the naming convention dictates that any symbol that ends in an asterix will provide very similar operation as the symbol without.

In the standard you have `let` that binds variables and `let*` which also binds variables but one at a time so that the created variables are available to the next bindings.

There are SRFIs that are a standard way of extending Scheme. Implementations implement many of the SRFIs native and those who don't can in many cases work with just downloading the reference implementation. [SRFI-89 implements](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-89/srfi-89.html) `define*` and `lambda*` and they provide Scheme with optional positional arguments. Looking at [Guile's SRFI support](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/SRFI-Support.html) SRFI-89 is not listed but the SRFI-89 itself mentions that Guile has them except it uses the notation `#:key` instead of `#!key`, thus not portable.

It's common for R5RS implementations to have more global bindings than the standard. If it's not a part of a SRFI you will be locked in by using such extensions.