# Warning from guile when using procedure from external file

Tags: module, scheme, external, guile

I have procedure that generate sha1 hash from string:

```
(define (string->sha1 string)
    (let ((port (open-input-string string)))
      (hex (sha1 port))))
```

the function hex and sha1 are taken from [A "pure" scheme implementation (R5RS) of SHA256?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093199/a-pure-scheme-implementation-r5rs-of-sha256) I've put the code in sha.scm and load using:

```
(load "sha.scm")
```

and I've got warnings like this:

```
;;; /home/kuba/projects/jcubic/notes/./rpc.scm:66:6: warning: possibly unbound variable `hex'
;;; /home/kuba/projects/jcubic/notes/./rpc.scm:66:11: warning: possibly unbound variable `sha1'
```

How can I resolve those warnings?

Comment: I think you should try `use-modules` instead of `load`. https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Using-Guile-Modules.html

Comment: @soegaard use-modules is for installed modules, but sha.scm is not a module is normal file, how can I use use-modules with normal file?

Comment: You need to turn sha.scm into a module first.